# Problem running BIRTViewer in Oracle Weblogic 14.1.1

Tags: birt, weblogic14c

I have created a war file of birt-runtime-4.12.0-20221128 as in the instructions for POJO deploymnet.  I am running weblogic 14.1.1 and I can successfully deploy it.  Weblogic is running Java Version:    1.8.0_331.  Is this sufficient?

When I browse to the following path:  http://localhost:7001/birt/index.jsp
I get the following error:  Error 404--Not Found

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

I tried building it many times and many ways and this is the only way that it successfully deployed but doesnt work.

Comment: Did you deploy the application ? Did you start it ? 
Any information or error in the weblogic log file ?

Comment: Yes, it deployed fine and weblogic console reported that it was started.  There were no errors in the weblogic logs that we looked at unless there is some other log we don't know about

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but BIRT 4.12 needs Java >= 11.

Comment: We upgraded to Java 11 and still have the same results

Comment: java version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 LTS

Comment: It seems that it runs fine in Linux but it doesnt run in Windows.   Any more suggestions?